# Strategy for fixing corrupted Core Data files

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, core-data, corruption

I know that core data corruption is supposed to be very rare, but I am getting some users who have corrupted stores -- for whatever reason. What are some strategies for fixing corrupted core data stores? I don't like having to tell my users, "I hope you made a backup!" Because most don't.

Comment: If you followed apple's rediculous rules about using CD in the cloud, you could just roll-back to a working copy.

Comment: Can you please explain more?

Comment: It would probably help to edit your question to add a description of the actual symptoms users encounter. Do they get bogus data for some instances? For all of them? Does the app just crash?

Comment: Hi @Jason. What did you do - how did you help your users? I am having the same problem right now.